# Show and Hidden TextView

Tags: android, textview

I need to show a hidden TextView and then re-hide it.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lectura"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

In Activity :

```
String codigo_leido = "";
EditText lectura;
String rut;
Boolean qr_code = false;
Boolean pdf_417 = false;
String title = "Eventrid";
TextView txtView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.validacion_bluetooth);
    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3d3d3d")));
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ticket_green);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + title + "</font>"));
    lectura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lectura);
    lectura.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F1F1"));
    lectura.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
            txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtView.setText("Validando...");
            //If the keyevent is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                codigo_leido = lectura.getText().toString();
                lectura.setText("");
                database nueva = new database();
                SessionManager sesion = new SessionManager();
                try{
                    if (nueva.containRuN(codigo_leido)){
                        qr_code = true;
                    }
                    if(!qr_code){
                        rut = nueva.getRutFromPDF147(codigo_leido);
                        if(!(rut.equals("") || rut == null) && nueva.isRut(rut)){
                            pdf_417 = true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
                sesion.setValue(ValidacionBlueTooth.this,"codigoLectura", codigo_leido);

                txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txtView.setText("");
                Intent intent = new Intent(ValidacionBlueTooth.this,Validador.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

After running an enter into a EditText I would like to show a hidden TextView. With this code it works great. But when I return to the previous Activity shown again.

Try these methods to re-hide the TextView but still not working. When pressing the back button event reappears the TextView.

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i("ff", "On Restart .....");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy();
    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i("ff", "On Destroy .....");
}
```

**EDIT**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the code in OnResume method. Also 
add a boolean flag

```
private Boolean ifPressedEditText = false;
```

Then change your setOnKeyListener:

```
 lectura.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey (View view,int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent){
        txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtView.setText("Validando...");
        //add this line...
        ifPressedEditText = true;
```

Add this code in onResume

```
        @Override
        protected void onResume () {
            super.onResume();
            //do a check if the user previosly pressed the edittext
            if (ifPressedEditText) {
                txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            Log.i("ff", "On Resume .....");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `super.onResume()`?

Comment: Just fixed that for @Georgi

Comment: Thanks, yes. It should be onResume. Thanks! @bearsmahoney

Comment: Dear, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this did not work for me. It continues to be right when the button is pressed again.

Comment: add picture @GeorgiKoemdzhiev

Comment: @sioesi Sorry, I cannot add a picture of the code since I am not actually testing it anywhere. I will try to find another way and edit my answer.

Comment: I said I add an image, when the back button is pressed as if pressed. Edit my post! @GeorgiKoemdzhiev

Comment: @sioesi This code should work. It should hide the text view (if the user has pressed the EditText before) when you press the back button.

Answer (score 0):

> With this code it works great. But when I return to the previous
>   Activity shown again.

**Docs says:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

> The introduction to Managing the `Activity Lifecycle` briefly mentions
>   that *when an activity is paused or stopped*, the state of the activity
>   is retained. This is true because the `Activity` object is still held in
>   memory **when it is paused or stopped—all** information about its members
>   and ***current state is still alive***. Thus, ***any changes*** the user made
>   within the activity are ***retained so that when the activity returns to
>   the foreground (when it "resumes"***), ***those changes are still there***.

And here is the point:

> However, when the system destroys an `Activity` in order to ***recover
>   memory***, the `Activity` **object is destroyed**, *so the system cannot simply
>   resume it with its state intact*. Instead, ***the system must recreate the
>   `Activity` object if the user navigates back to it***. Yet, the user is
>   unaware that the system destroyed the activity and recreated it and,
>   thus, probably expects the activity to be exactly as it was. In this
>   situation, you can ensure that important information about the
>   activity state is preserved by implementing an additional callback
>   method that allows you to save information about the state of your
>   activity: onSaveInstanceState().

That was the interesting part.So, you should do that when the `Activity` is in the `onResume`.

or if that didn't work, try to use [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Answer (score 0):

You can samply manage visibilty on TextView.

```
txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
or 
txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
or
txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

you can used as per requirement.